# Setting up periodic SLA warnings in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a scenario for Dynamics CRM Online as follows: On the case entity, the maximum time allowed for case resolution is 48 hours, the first warning email should go out after 24 hours of case creation. If the case is not resolved within 48 hours a warning email should go out every 12 hours till it is resolved. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is implementing a scheduled EXE to look at the open cases and send the emails, CRM isn't really designed for this kind of recurring operations.

You'd be able to leverage Email Templates from SDK aswell, so it's actually not a hard at all solution (that's how we implement this kind of requirement usually too)

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) integrates with CRM Online and allows you to configure scheduled workflows.

Answer (score 0):

**CRM 2011**

You should try Timeout (Wait is other option) in CRM Workflow to achieve the requirement.

http://www.powerobjects.com/2012/10/12/time-condition-based-workflows-in-crm-2011/

While creating case & after the reminder sent, you can set the next checkpoint time & workflow can send the reminder email once checkpoint time is reached (after checking the current status)

**CRM 2013**

SLA feature is introduced & refer the below link to implement it

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmusings/archive/2014/06/09/dynamics-crm-2013-part-iii-service-management-sla-39-s

Comment: like @Alex mentioned, Scheduled Exe also give you more control